# Using AWS for SQL and REST frontend

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, rest, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up a PostgreSQL db with a REST(php) gate. I want to access this database the standard REST way (using GET and Headers), from a C# application.

Currently I am using a standard web hoster that has a MySQL database, but I want to jump ship to PostgreSQL.

Am I right in thinking Amazon's EC2 servers a good choice to do this? I just need a server with PostgreSQL installed and a bunch of php scripts (for REST).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

EC2 would work fine, or you could use an RDS PostgreSQL instance, and just run the PHP scripts on a small EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [restSQL](http://restsql.org). It's an open-source, ultra-lightweight persistence layer, with out of the box PostgreSQL support.

It's written in Java but you can use its HTTP API by deploying the service in a standard JEE container, e.g. Tomcat, or as a Docker container. The latest versions are on bundled as images on docker hub.

You can take it for a spin using the sandboxed instance and explore the docs at http://restsql.org.